# Number of operations of a k-ary search algorithm when k=4?

Tags: algorithm, search, pseudocode

I am analyzing the complexities of the search algorithms. e.g for binary search whose pseudocode is given below I can write that

5 operations (3 assignments, 1 subtraction, 1 comparison) outside the loop.

7 operations (2 additions, 1 division, 2 comparisons, 2 assignments) at each loop run.

```
int binary_search(int x, int a[], int n)
{
int i, j, location;
int m;
i = 0;
j = n-1;
while (i < j) {
m = (i + j) / 2;
if (x > a[m]) i = m+1;
else j = m;
}
if (x == a[i]) location = i;
else location = -1;
return location;
}
```

I am trying to do the same for a k-ary search algorithm when k = 4, but I couldn't find a pseudocode which I can analyize. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another question which I asked and again I answered after a few days of struggle. With some help from the internet, I wrote a java code that works properly with acm library. the number we are looking for is x, the j is the last index of our set and the array is in an increasing order. by changing these parameters, we can look for any number in any array by using 4-ary algorithm.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import acm.program.*;


public class quartersearch extends ConsoleProgram {


    public void run() {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 15;
        int location;
        int x = 6;

        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

        println(a[2]);

        while ( i < j) {
            int l = (j + 3*i) /4 ;  // 1st divisor
            int m = (j + i) / 2;  // 2nd divisor
            int u = (3*j + i) / 4; // 3rd divisor
            if(x > a[u]) { 
                i = u + 1;
            } else if ( x > a[m] && x <= a[u]) {
                i = m + 1;
                j = u;
            } else if (x > a[l] && x <= a[m]) {
                i = l + 1;
                j = m;
            } else {
                j = l;
            }   
        } 


        int k = (i+j) / 2;
        if (a[i] == x) {
            location = i;
        } else if (a[k] == x) {
            location = k;
        } else if (a[j] == x) {
            location = j;
        } else {
            location = 0;
        }

        println(location);

    }






}
```